# python - webbrowser module opens only a specific link in a different browser

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Safari as my default browser. It opens only `forvo.com` in Firefox and the remaining links in Safari. I get the following error:
`0:45: execution error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)`

I tried exception handling. 
Once I remove `forvo.com` everything works as intended.

```
import webbrowser


voc = "test"
links = (
    "http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/" + voc,
    "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + voc +
        "&biw=1250&bih=782&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_3vGFt67NAhWFApoKHREWC94Q_AUIBygC",
    "http://forvo.com/search/" + voc + "/"
        )

for i in links:
    webbrowser.open(i)
```

Comment: I tested your code with **Firefox** but I do not get the error message you have.

Comment: With Firefox as default browser, it works smoothly on my mac.